# Can I add another suitcase in one of my connecting flights?

Tags: luggage, connecting-flights

I am flying from A to B, with a connecting flight through London Heathrow (i.e. A -> LHR -> B). Both flights are with the same company/conglomerate, and so my bags will still be in transit (and not with me).

I have a 10 hours wait in LHR and want to go downtown and do some substantial shopping (including alcohol). I plan to **buy another suitcase**, fill it with these shopping, and then dropping at the bag drop, so I can have it at my final destination.

Is it possible to do this? Can I add another suitcase in one of my flight connections?

Comment: Accept as duplicate, although the answer is not entirely satisfactory